# apache2 misconfiguration, appends infinite /index.html/ to url

Tags: 301-redirect, apache2

I use the bash under Windows 10 with apache2 and php7 installed.

I set up a vhost for http://localhost mapped to a symbolic file which is linked to a physical windows directory.
When I open the url, it infinitely appends /index.html/ to the url, regardless of which subdirectories I enter regardless of (existing) files in the url, like this:

```
http://localhost/pub/videos/viewsSimilarities_movie.mp4
```

leads to:

```
http://localhost/pub/videos/viewsSimilarities_movie.mp4/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/
```

and

```
http://localhost/pub/
```

leads to:

```
http://localhost/pub/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/
```

My /etc/apache2/sites-available/localhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DirectoryIndex index.html

        <Directory /var/www/html>
#               Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                RewriteEngine Off
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/localhost_error.log
        LogLevel debug
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/localhost_access.log combined

# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration
Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
<Directory /var/www/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag track_vars On
    php_flag register_globals Off
    php_value include_path .
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The Options line doesn't change anything.

Where can I look for the problem?

Comment: The entry `DirectoryIndex index.html` belongs inside of `<Directory /var/www/html>`. Also note that your Options are commented out (this is not causing the problem though).

Comment: As always start in your log files. Typically such is the result of incorrect rewrite rules, although you correctly have `AllowOverride None` you might still want to check for .htaccess files.

Comment: What's inside the index.html? There is nothing in that configuration that will cause such redirect. Try the same request with curl if you can use it like `curl -I http://localhost/pub/videos/viewsSimilarities_movie.mp4` and show the output. Also show the relevant access_log entries and error_log entries if any.